# Running Java from an OSX ".app" bundle causes "Error -10810"

Tags: java, macos, bash, packaging

This was tested on OSX Mavericks through virtual box, and on Yosemite on a macbook.

I have a simple executable jar named "HelloWorld.jar".

I am trying to create a .app bundle for this java application. (Obviously, my actual program is more complex, but I have whittled it down to the barest problems).

---

## CASE 1 - SIMPLE BUNDLE WITHOUT JAVA - WORKS COMPLETELY

### Step 1 - Test at Console - Works

At the console I type

`echo "Hello World (no java)" > /Users/josh/Desktop/test-output.txt`

I view test-output.txt and see the expected output.

### Step 2 - Test with Script - Works

I make a simple bash script named `test`:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "Hello World (no java)" > /Users/josh/Desktop/test-output.txt
```

I `chmod +x test` and then type `./test`, I view test-output.txt and see the expected output.

### Step 3 - Create Rudimentary App Bundle - Works

```
mkdir -p test.app/Contents/MacOS
cp test test.app/Contents/MacOS
open test.app
```

I view test-output.txt and see the expected output.

---

## CASE 2 - SIMPLE BUNDLE WITH JAVA - DOES NOT WORK

### Setup

File `HelloWorld.java`:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println ( "Hello World" );
    }
}
```

File `myManifest`

```
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

Did the following at console:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
jar -cfm HelloWorld.jar myManifest HelloWorld.class
```

### Step 1 - Test at Console - Works

At the console I type:

`java -jar HelloWorld.jar > /Users/josh/Desktop/java-output.txt`

I get the expected output: `Hello World`

### Step 2 - Test with Script - Works

I make a simple bash script named "helloworld"

```
 #!/bin/bash
 java -jar HelloWorld.jar > /Users/josh/Desktop/java-output.txt
```

I `chmod +x helloworld` and then type `./helloworld`, I get the expected output: `Hello World`

### Step 3 (With Java) - Does not Work

```
mkdir -p helloworld.app/Contents/MacOS
cp helloworld helloworld.app/Contents/MacOS
cp HelloWorld.jar helloworld.app/Contents/MacOS
open helloworld.app
```

I get the following error:

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/josh/Desktop/helloworld/helloworld.app`

`/user/Josh/desktop/java-output.txt` appears, but has no text inside.

---

As you can see, it appears that something is happening where running java inside an .app bundle is giving me that -10810 error.

Note: I also tried a variation of the first example, where I had the bash script launch /Applications/TextEdit.app, and that worked successfully. It makes me suspect the problem is with java specifically.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can create a sufficiently complete bundle doing only what you've shown here. How 'bout using appbundler? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

Comment: "Case 1" suggests to me that the bundle is complete.  I wrestled with appbundler for a few days on my windows machine, but was never able to get a working bundle from it.

Comment: Have you verified that it is not  a PATH issue by using the full path to Java inside the bash script that you're copying into the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not currently have an OS X machine handy  to test this, but hints on the web from [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/682260/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-gui-apps-in-os-x-mavericks) seem to imply that you need to set `JAVA_HOME` and possibly `PATH` in order to make `java` work inside the app bundle.

Specifically, at the top of your shell script, before attempting to run your program, put the following lines, with appropriate changes for your system.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/my/java/install
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory/containing/java
```

More generally, to diagnose the root cause of the problem, change the existing line in your script to capture `stderr` and see if that gives you any useful output that might have otherwise been swallowed by the app's environment.

```
 java -jar HelloWorld.jar > /Users/josh/Desktop/java-output.txt  2>  /Users/josh/Desktop/java-error.txt
```

If you are able to capture the printed error, it may suffice to show you root cause.

Comment: Thanks. I will test this tonight and let you know the results.

Comment: Same error at the console. java-error.txt says "Error: Unable to access jarfile HelloWorld.jar"

Comment: I'll look into this and get back to you.

Comment: Added a "pwd" to the script. When I run it normally, it reports the current directory. However, when it's in the .app, it reports "/" is the working directory. I think this may be the problem, not sure how to fix it yet.

Comment: Use absolute path for the jar.

Comment: Yea, got it working with this: DIR=`dirname $0; java -jar $DIR/HelloWorld.jar. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: For some reason it won't met me award the bounty for six hours. I will award it once it lets me. :-)