# Java Mac application failed with error code -10810

Tags: java, macos

I'm making a Java application in Eclipse that needs to run on both Windows and Mac. I made it into a Mac app that I'm able to run independent of Eclipse on my laptop, but when I tried to run it through terminal on another Mac machine (that had the Java version that I required), it showed the error message:

Cannot run (/Users/agastya/Desktop/appname.app). Error Code: -10810. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you executing it? In Eclipse? Commandline?

Comment: When double-clicked, it runs a shell script that executes the JAR file with my code in it.

Comment: Does it give any other output except the error code?

Comment: No it doesn't give any other output

Comment: what is in the shell script?

Comment: Just a shebang and this line: `java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar ./DEC.jar`

Answer (score 1):

1. try to run the application from terminal
2. please use the full path to appname.app

Comment: Running it from Terminal was how I saw the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be that you need to set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`

Please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531128/running-java-from-an-osx-app-bundle-causes-error-10810)

Comment: What would I need to set the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables to? Would I need to do that in a Shell script? Sorry if these are dumb questions, this is completely new to me.